# Google script - Delay in the function

Tags: google-apps-script

I am running this code in sequence editor o google sheet.
I need the script to run seconds after the spreadsheet is modified.
It works but it the delay function is not taking it.
what is my error? thanks!!!

```
 function myFunction(e) {
  var url = 'https://exaple.com/?iwp=run&hash=abc123';
  Utilities.sleep(10000);
  var options = {
 'method': 'get'
 };

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
  Logger.log(response);
   }
```

Comment: how are you invoking the function?

Comment: The url imports the data from google sheet to wordpress. It works perfect if I copy it in the browser.
The problem is that it runs before the Google sheet reads the data of the new row (it brings them form)

Comment: You could use a client side Javascript timer to do this.  I have one described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55786303/7215091) .  It would be easy to set up a 10 second timer as long as you don't mind having a sidebar running at the same time.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I see it interesting but it can not be done without the bar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im not sure about delays but you could try using triggers.It can be set to do an action after the spreadsheet has been updated.

Link:https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/

Link:https://courses.benlcollins.com/courses/apps-script-blastoff/lectures/8427243 (There is a example here)

Comment: Hi Adrian! I have a configured trigger when I update as the video this import but not the last row. It seems that the problem of time...

Comment: So there is already a working trigger that will run the program when data is updated in google sheets but the delay is not working?

Comment: yes exactly only it works when the trigger is configured by times, like five minutes, etc. when I set the trigger when editing or opening the table it does not work ... although a complete row is created from mysql.

Comment: Have u tried to take out the delay portion in the script,and set the trigger to happen on data change?

Comment: do you mean delete `Utilities.sleep(10000);`? yes. I ran this code for the first time that i tried.. and with the function configurated on edit . Do you want a screenshot?

Comment: Will let u know if there is any solution i can find.