# How can I bypass the invoked too many times error?

Tags: google-maps, google-apps-script, google-sheets, upgrade, account

I am trying to use the following script to populate the zip codes for over 3000 cells:

```
function geo2zip(a) {
  var response=Maps.newGeocoder()
 .reverseGeocode(lat(a),long(a));
 return response.results[0].formatted_address.split(',') 
  [2].trim().split(' ')[1];
   }
 function lat(pointa) {
 var response = Maps.newGeocoder()
 .geocode(pointa);
  return response.results[0].geometry.location.lat
  }
  function long(pointa) {
  var response = Maps.newGeocoder()
 .geocode(pointa);
  return response.results[0].geometry.location.lng
   }
```

Obviously, after about 5 cells I am getting the error that the service has been invoked too many times

Simply, how do I pay (or add to the code) to be able to run the script for the cells I need?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the delay.  You'll have to play with it probably.  And I'm also not sure if you'll be allowed to get 3000 operations in one day.  But disregarding quotas for the moment, **which I wouldn't recommend**, you could do something like this.

It looks like this service is on a pay as you go basis so my guess is that it will cost you something.  Read the links at the bottom about API use and Billing.

```
function loopGeocode(start) {
  var start=start || 0;
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh1=ss.getSheetByName('Points');
  var sh2=ss.getSheetByName('Locations');
  var pt=sh1.getRange(1, 1,sh.getLastRow(),1).getValues();
  for(var i=start;i<pt.length;i++) {
    sh2.appendRow([i+1,pt[i][0],geo2zip(pt[i][0])])
    Utilities.sleep(8000);//I have no idea what this delay should be
  }
  return i+1;
}

function geo2zip(a) {
  var response=Maps.newGeocoder().reverseGeocode(lat(a),long(a));
  return response.results[0].formatted_address.split(',')[2].trim().split(' ')[1];
}
function lat(pointa) {
  var response = Maps.newGeocoder().geocode(pointa);
  return response.results[0].geometry.location.lat
}
function long(pointa) {
  var response = Maps.newGeocoder().geocode(pointa);
  return response.results[0].geometry.location.lng
}
```

I'd run it off of a JavaScript timer and try running once every 6 minutes. I don't know if the withSuccessHandler() will wait that long so you might need to store the return value which tells the loop where to start counting every time. You could probably store in PropertiesService.  It will take about 15 hours.

[Geocoding API Use and Billing](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/usage-and-billing#new-payg)

[Geocoding API Getting Started](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/start)

[Javascript Timer Example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55786303/7215091)

> After reading some of the links I would believe that 50 queries per second is acceptable so the solution may have nothing to do with adding time between samples. It's probably a matter of setting up a billing account and pay as you go.

[Create, Modify, or Close Your Billing Account](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/manage-billing-account)